# PHP Rest API Create product Not Working

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to create a woo commerce  product using Rest API Provided i have  a Consumer Key: and Consumer Secret: With read and Write Authentication am not sure where am going wrong the PHP is not populating any error message nor the Product Was Created.

```
<?php


    require_once 'class-wc-api-client.php';





function addProduct()
{      

    $options = array(
        'debug'           => false,
        'return_as_array' => false,
        'validate_url'    => false,
        'timeout'         => 30,
        'ssl_verify'      => false,
    );

    try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client(  'http://example.com/demo/workpressistalledlocation/','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',$options );



        $client->products->create(  array(  'sku' => '100001',  'title' => 'Superduper product',   'type' => 'simple',  'regular_price' => '21.50', 'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',  'short_description' => 'Short description for product'));

print_r( $completed_orders );
    } catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

        if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {

            print_r( $e->get_request() );
            print_r( $e->get_response() );
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: `$completed_orders` this variable is not initailized..

Answer (score 1):

**You could try this if you haven't found answer yet.**

**Use only if you are using woo-commerce rest api v2/v3 version**

```
            $product = array(
            'title' => 'title_of_product',
            'sku' => 'unique_sku',
            'regular_price' => 'price',
            'type' => 'simple/variable/grouped/external',
            'description' => $this->tftimport_description,
            'managing_stock' => $manage_wc_stock,
            'status' => 'draft',
            'enable_html_description' => true,
        );

        $wc_product = $this->get_wc_api_client()->products->create($product);
```

You could also check for more help on  rest api from woocommerce offical api documenation linke below :

> https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product